# Help with proper character encoding

Tags: php, portability, character-encoding

I have a HTML form that is sometimes submitted with accented characters: à, è, ì, ò, ù

I have a PHP script that exports these form submissions into CSV format, when I look at the CSV format in a text editor (vim or notepad for example) the characters look fine, but when opened with Open Office or Word, I get some funky results: �����

I am also passing these submission to salesforce and am getting an error: "The entity "Atilde" was referenced, but not declared."

What can I do to ensure portability of my CSV file? What's the proper way to handle the encoding?

My HTML file is content-type is set as: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Data is being stored in MySQL as latin1_swedish_ci collation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total encoding confusion! :-)

#### The table character set

The MySQL table character set only determines what encoding MySQL should use internally, and thus the range of characters permitted.

- If you set it to Latin-1 (aka [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)), you will not be able to store international characters in your table.
- Importantly, the character set does not affect the encoding MySQL uses when communicating with your PHP script.
- The table *collation* specifies rules for sorting.

#### The connection character set

The MySQL [connection character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html) determines the encoding you receive table data in (and should send data to MySQL in).

- The encoding is set using SET NAMES, e.g. `SET NAMES "utf8"`.
- If this does not match the table encoding, MySQL automatically converts data on the fly.
- If this does not match your page character set, you'll have to manually perform character set conversion in PHP, using e.g. [utf8_encode](http://www.php.net/utf8_encode) or [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/mb-convert-encoding).

#### Page character set

The page character set, specified using the [Content-Type header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17), tells the browser how to interpret the PHP script output.

- As an HTTP header, it is not saved when you save the file from within your browser. The information is thus not available to OpenOffice or other programs.

#### Recommendations

Ideally, you should use the same encoding in all three places, and ideally, that encoding should be UTF-8.

However, CSV will cause problems, since the file format does not include encoding information. It is thus up to the application to guess the encoding, and as you've seen, the guess will be wrong.

- I don't know about OpenOffice, but Microsoft Office will assume the Windows "ANSI" encoding, which usually means Latin-1 (or [CP1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) to be specific).
- Microsoft Office will also cause problems in [countries that use "," as a decimal separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.png), since Office then switches to using ";" as a field separator for CSV-files.

Your best bet is to use Latin-1 for the CSV-file. I'd still use UTF-8 for the table and connection character sets though, and also UTF-8 for HTML pages.

If you use UTF-8 for the connection character set (by executing `SET NAMES "utf8"` after connecting), you'll need to run the text through utf8_decode to convert to Latin-1.

#### That entity problem

> I am also passing these submission to salesforce and am getting an error: "The entity "Atilde" was referenced, but not declared."

This sounds like you're passing HTML code in an XML context, and is unrelated to character sets. Try running the text through [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/html-entity-decode).

Comment: Latin-1 is not the same thing as cp1252. Windows doesn't use Latin-any_number.

Comment: I never said they were. However, we can ignore the differences in this case, since CP1252 is a superset of Latin-1. If you emit valid Latin-1, you're thus also emitting valid CP1252.

For those interested in the difference, I provided a link to the Wikipedia page on CP1252. But then we haven't even discussed the difference between "ISO-8859-1" and "ISO 8859-1".

Answer (score 0):

Also, what document type have you set, is it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Try using the **[htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)** function for any text that is not showing correctly.

You may also want to have a look PHP **[Normalizer](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php)**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are writing the CSV file as UTF-8. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#55054 if you are unsure how to.

(Also, your sql table should be using utf8, not latin1)

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to decide which charset encoding you'll use for writing your CSV file (but, note, that must be a concious decision on your part).

Which charset encoding to use ?  CSV does not defines a charset encoding - So I'd go for some Unicode charset, presumably UTF8. But some CSV consumers (eg Excel) might not be happy with it. If you are restricted to "western" langs, then latin1 or its variants (iso-8859-1 or iso-8859-15) might be more appropiate. But then (in any case, actually) you must think the conversion from user input to your particular encoding - and what to do if there are invalid characters.

(BTW: same consideration goes for the html-input-to-db conversion - you are using latin1 for your database, have you asked yourself what happens if the user types a non-latin1 character ? eg a japanese char ? ).